# Apache and tomcat in the same Virtualhost

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxypass

I have a virtualhost that looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    RedirectMatch ^/manager$ http://www.fna.fi/manager/
    DocumentRoot /build/vhosts/mysite.com
    ErrorLog /build/logs/site.com-error.log
    CustomLog /build/logs/site.com-access.log combined
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine on

    ProxyPass /manager http://127.0.0.1:8060/manager/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse /manager http://127.0.0.1:8060/manager

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8060/app/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8060/app/
 </VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to add a blog in /build/vhosts/mysite.com. So it will be : http://www.mysite.com/blog but when I access this site it looks like its being forwarded to Tomcat (most likely due to the "ProxyPass /...".

Is there a way to make it work for the scenario I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently anything will be forwarded to the tomcat:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8060/app/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8060/app/
```

You have to add a alias **before** your proxy directives to your config:

```
Alias /blog /build/vhosts/mysite.com
<Location /blog>
    # make some configs for this location like...
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Location>
```

Comment: Can you please show what your log tells when you make a request to http://www.mysite.com/blog?

Comment: Its a 404 message : - - [01/Apr/2012:09:20:39 +0200] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 404 3626 "-"

Comment: Its because its using the Tomcat server on / ..and there there is no /blog.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was sure, that the defined location catches the request first and delivers the content. I need to check it out on my own test server.

Comment: Fix was to use ProxyPass /blog ! as described in here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html